# the mean number of fixed points of a finite endomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

for some reason i found myself wondering what is the average number of fixed points of an endomorphism of a finite set. after floundering around for a while i obtained a result that surprised me.

**question** is the following arithmetic correct? if it is, is there a simple intuitive explanation that might give the result without the hard labour?

let $R_n$ be a finite point set of cardinality $n$ and denote by $p_{n,k}$ the probability that a randomly chosen endomorphism $\phi$ of $R_n$ has exactly $k$ fixed points. since the $\phi$-invariant subset of $R_n$ can be chosen in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, and each of the $n-k$ non-fixed points can be assigned by $\phi$ to any of $n-1$ points, we have
$$
p_{n,k}=n^{-n}\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^{n-k}
$$
if $\mu_n$ is the average number of fixed points over all endomorphisms then
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_n & = \sum_{k=0}^n k p_{n,k} \\  & = n^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(n-1)^{n-k} k \\
& =\left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(n-1)^{-k} k \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
to sum the series on the right, note that for any $x$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^k = x \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k = nx(1+x)^{n-1}
$$
setting $x-\frac1{n-1}$, and plugging the result back into (1),  after a little simplification this gives $\mu_n=1$.

Comment: "Linearity of expectation" is the magic phrase; each point has expectation $1/n$ of being fixed, there are $n$ points, so expected number fixed is 1.

Comment: thanks, Gerry. i can see that now.

Comment: By endomorphism, do you just mean "permutation"?

Comment: @Jack no, endomorphism is a rather awkard word for a fundamental concept. in the category of sets an endomorphism is any mapping of a set into itself. the endomorphisms form a non-commmutative monoid (under function composition). for a finite set, relative to an ordering of its $n$ elements, this monoid can be represented as a set of matrices such that every row has exactly one element $=1$ and the rest zero. the operation is ordinary matrix multiplication. the permutations are the submonoid of invertible elements, and thus form a group (isomorphic to $S_n$)

Comment: note that the $n$ constant endomorphisms form a sumbonoid of idempotents in which each element is a left identity